# How to change textView value when getting a notification?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm trying to make a program where the value of a TextView is changed when a notification appears on the phone.

In my MainActivity I have a method:

```
private void changeText(){
    TextView textNotificationView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textNotificationView);
    textNotificationView.setText(R.string.textGotNotification);
}
```

I would like to call `changeText()` from MainActivity whenever I get a notification. For this I have created a class called NotificationListener that extends NotificationListenerService.

```
public class NotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return super.onBind(intent);
}

@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    //Change value of TextView
}

@Override
public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn){

}
}
```

Basically, I would like to call the `changeText()`-method inside the `onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn)`-method.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a solution, that is using EventBus

first, create a event

```
public class NotificationPosted {
// empty if you don't need to pass data
}
```

second, register this event in `MainActivity`

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onStop();
}




  @Subscribe(sticky = true, threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
        public void onEvent(NotificationPosted notificationPosted) {
            changeText()
        }
```

finally, post your event in `NotificationListener`

```
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    EventBus.getDefault().post(new NotificationPosted());
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!! Is the NotificationPosted-class just supposed to stay empty?

Comment: Yep. NotificationPosted is an event for EventBus to handle. But if you need to send data, then use params in the NotificationPosted class, to access it in Activity.

Answer (score 1):

You need an callback from your non-activity class to `Activity` class.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements INotificationCallback {  
    public void setText(String value) {
        TextView textNotificationView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textNotificationView);
        textNotificationView.setText(value);
    }  
}

public NotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {
    public interface INotificationCallback {
        public void setText(String value);
    }   

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        activity.setText(value); 
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!